# Moto 360 Location Symbol

Tags: android-wear, motorola-moto-360

I was doing some development work on my Moto 360 (using Android Studio), and since I rebooted the watch earlier to fix an issue with Android Studio, this location symbol has been on my watchface. What does that symbol mean?

Notes:

- This symbol acts exactly like the offline "cloud" symbol acts, regardless of watchface.
- The app I'm working on does not access my watch's or phone's location in any way.
- Debugging over Bluetooth setting in Android Wear app turned off, as well as Bluetooth Debugging and ADB Debugging settings in Developer Settings on my watch.
- Some app was using my location for hours on my phone, but has since stopped, while this location symbol has persisted.
- Never seen this symbol before on my watch, and haven't done a software update recently or anything.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

**What could that symbol mean? How can I get it to go away?**

Comment: Could that be *driving* related app which gets triggered on motion and reads out SMS aloud for instance ( I have that on Moto X Play currently disabled)

Comment: @beeshyams Nope, that space is reserved for system icons (apps can't put anything there and I've never seen anything but DND and Offline icons there). Anyway, I got it to go away, but I'm not really sure how.

Comment: To get the icon to go away, I toggled Airplane Mode on and then off, restarted my watch (Settings -> Restart watch), accidentally booted into recovery mode (?), powered on normally, and voila!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the symbol that denotes an app is using your current location. Common apps to use this are the Maps, Lyft, and Weather apps. If it persists for some reason, just try toggling on/off airplane mode or restarting your watch from settings.

I figured this out by opening up Lyft, closing it quickly, and returning to my watchface where that symbol was there for just a second before disappearing.